# Swift - How do I place a page-view within a UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uipageviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

I am using Swift 3, Xcode 8.2.

I have an application where the user launches the iPhone camera and I give them a popup with instructions on how to take a good picture.  I want there to be a way to create pages within the `UIAlertController`.  I did a quick sketch of what I want to achieve.

[image]

Code wise, I am not sure what to do:

```
func displayInstructions() {

    let insController = UIAlertController(title: "Instructions", message: "Step 1: Do this.", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let actionDone = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        //This is called when the user presses the cancel button.
        print("You've pressed the done button");
    }


    //Add the buttons
    errorController.addAction(actionDone)

    // Some way to addSubviews here??  
    let pageViewController: UIPageViewController
    insController.addSubview(pageViewController)

    //Present the instruction controller
    self.present(insController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property on `UIAlertController`, not advertised in public API but that seem usable without trouble going through the app store review. So, using KVC, you can set the `contentViewController` of the alert controller.

```
let pageViewController: UIPageViewController

// configure pageViewController...
insController.setValue(pageViewController, forKey: "contentViewController")
```

You can also set the size of the `contentViewController` by setting `preferredContentSize.height` on it

```
pageViewController.preferredContentSize.height = 180
```

---

This is what the result looks like with an empty page view controller

[image: UIAlertController with nested page view controller]

Comment: Nice! But do you have any reference for this? Only concern is that it might change.

Comment: Indeed it might. I've read about this on stack overflow, there are a lot of question about the subject around. But, it works for now and we simply need to be careful on os updates I guess ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This is just what I needed.  Thank you so much.  You are a life saver.